# weird Demodulated BPSK waveform

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, demodulation, bpsk

[image][image]

I am using an acoustic wave of 3khz(audio BPSK) as my carrier frequency with a sampling rate of 10k samples per bit. at the receiver end, I play the audio from my phone to my computer, record it through matlab and try to demodulate it but my received signal has a weird shape, unlike the transmitted signal. the received signal above is what I was expecting, does anyone know why this may happen?

Comment: Is that picture the received signal after basebanding? Could you post a picture of what you expect? Also, what is your symbol period? It’s hard to tell from the given information, but I think you may need to increase your carrier frequency. Basebanding the received signal does not recover the original signal before mixing with the carrier frequency. There is still leftover spectral content from the carrier frequency that gets filtered out by the matched filter. If the carrier frequency is lower than the cutoff of the matched filter it will interfere with the signal. Posting code may help too.

Comment: iam using BPSK modulation scheme  so after multiplying the received signal my bit duration is every 10k samples.  and I didn't use a match filter, I multiplied the signal with cos(2pifct) to get the baseband signal out.

Comment: From my understanding, your bitrate is 1 bit per second, your carrier is 3KHz and your phone DAC samples at 10 ksps? Are you sure of the signal transmitted?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely seeing the effects of frequency offset between the transmitter and receiver in which case the original signal will have an envelope that varies at the frequency offset between the two.

Typically a carrier recovery is implemented to determine what the offset frequency is and correct it in the receiver clock such that it is synchronized to the transmitter.

If the clocks are confirmed to be synchronized then this may be caused by an insufficient low pass filter given a multiplier demodulator is used (which will pass a sum frequency at 2x the carrier and a difference frequency as the demodulated signal).

Comment: I see it now. That does look like frequency offset.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot!!! it was the clocks I played and received the signals all on my computer and the weird effect has significantly reduced, the bits are in some trials turning out to be flipped ie all 1s, become 0s and vice verse but its still the correct values do you know why this could happen thanks

Comment: Yes that is totally expected with BPSK since the constellation is identical if you flip everything 180 degrees. One typically uses some approach to eliminate this 180 degree phase ambiguity such as a known preamble pattern or flipping if the BER is excessively high.